# C# filling dataGrid from other form

Tags: c#

I would like to add data from a fill out form I made, to another form which contains my DataGridView. The problem is that they dont see one another. I tried making a struct of those data fields(textboxes and comboboxes) and making a static list which I wanted to use in the other form with the table. But it still doesnt work.
I have a form Statue and a form Table. I tried

```
foreach('struct i made in both forms' rs in 'Statue.that static list')
{
-fill table-
}
```

but it displays error "cannot convert type Statue.registeStruct to Table.registreStruct". Can you help me with this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using mouse select your component in Visual Studio (I mean that dataGrid). Then go to property list, and change row "Modifiers" from private to public. Not you can access that dataGrid from another form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [**`Windows Forms`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You want to use [**`DataBinding`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I firmly suggest that you have a [**`BindingSource`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) per [**`DataGridView`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview), and then expose the its [**`DataSource`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in order to share the same source between the two.

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    public IList<MyObjectType> DataContext {
        get { return (IList<MyObjectType>)myBindingSource.DataSource; }
        set { myBindingSource.DataSource = value; }
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form {
    public IList<MyObjectType> DataContext {
        get { return (IList<MyObjectType>)myBindingSource.DataSource; }
        set { myBindingSource.DataSource = value; }
    }
}
```

Then, in another form, you'll be able to share the information between the two.

```
public class Form3 : Form {
    private void onWhateverEventItMIghtBe(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        instanceOfForm2.DataContext = instnceOfForm1.DataContext;
    }
}
```

You will indeed need to set data binding up in designer mode.

Set your `BindingSource.DataSource` property in the `PropertyWindow` to a new `DataSource` using the wizard in order  for both your `DataGridView` to set up their columns to what you want. Then, set you [**`DataGridView.DataSource`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource) property to your `BindingSource`.

Comment: Are those methods you wrote for two tables, because I only have one. I need to get filled out data from my Statue form to the Table form which contains my dataGridview and fill it up. I added the bind source to the datagrid, but what do I do at the Statue form side? Thank you for your fast reply

Comment: You'll have to update your question so that I may be of further assistance. Your question is about how to pass data along from one form to another, whatever that data may be, as long as it is of the same type as stated by `MyObjectType`.

Comment: If you have only one table, then the same `DataTable` could be used instead of `MyObjectType` to determine the type of your `IList<T>` in order to contain the same data. So same types, same properties, same data.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was swamped. I have one form and one table where I want that data to go in.I tried also making an instance of the table class and from that instance to get to the table, but now I cant seem to figure out how to fill it with data. I wrote table.tableStatue.Rows.Add(4); to add 4 rows under my columns but it doesnt add them. Is there something I am doing wrong? Thank you again

Comment: Please provide code sample which would state the way you're loading your data.

Comment: I fixed it adding a custom function which needs a datagridview parameter and adds data to it, which is called in the data fillout form... Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Looks like a code smell to me. You never pass a control as a parameter, except for event handling (`sender`). Anyway, the most important for now is that it works, I guess. Glad if I could be of any help. =)